# Total time elapsed for each day CakePHP & MySQL

Tags: mysql, cakephp

```
id  track_id    start                 stop                  created
4   7           2011-09-28 22:22:21   2011-09-28 22:22:30   2011-09-28 22:22:21
3   7           2011-09-28 22:22:07   2011-09-28 22:22:12   2011-09-28 22:22:07
```

Given the mysql structure and data above and the model name of Lapse. What sort of find/conditions would i use to get the output in array format:

```
2011-09-28 => 1 minute (or the total calculation of Stops - Starts)
```

So i can output a date and total elapsed time for that day?

Thanks

Comment: Yes and no. Its the same principle but this is more complex. The other is a basic theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but try something along this line: `'fields'=>array('SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Model.stop) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Model.start))')` and `'group'=>'DATE_FORMAT(Model.created,"%Y-%m-%d")'`

Comment: This is awesome. However it puts it into its own array, how could i have it in Cakes '"Lapse" =>' format?

Comment: glad that it works. About the array: you'll need to change that yourself after the find.